# Tomcat throwing 500 internal server error on SOAPFault

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS for SOAP Web Services. And implemented SOAPHandler to do authentication. On successful authentication return true, if fails throw an exception.

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context)
{
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = context.getMessage();
    if (authenticateUser(soapMessage)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Authentication failed!");
    }
}
```

While authentication failure I am supposed to get below SOAPFault.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.Exception: Authentication failed!</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

This is working fine in development world (eclipse/tomcat7).
But not working in production environment. In prod it simply returns 500 - Internal server error.

Why is this behavior?

Comment: and the stacktrace is?

Comment: Stacktrace has the exception am throwing "java.lang.Exception: Authentication failed!".

Comment: Please post the code of `authenticateUser` method

Comment: For time being it simply returns false.. so hat the request always enter the else part.

Comment: You mention the dev environment is eclipse/tomcat7. What is the production environment - also Tomcat 7 or something else?

Comment: Also, like @Paizo mentions, please post the full stack trace. I suspect you may be seeing your exception but it is being caught by the runtime and being wrapped in an `UndeclaredThrowableException`, meaning the app server interprets the `RuntimeException` as an unhandled, internal app error.  This would show up in the stack trace as one exception with a `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Authentication failed!` sort of line.

Comment: I am not getting that exception in application layer. Tomcat is behind IIS and seems like something is going wrong while relaying SOAPFault. Anyway I changed the logic and now returning an STATUS with ERROR object rather than throwing exception. Thanks guys..